# Error in as_mapper(.f, ...) : object 'validate' not found

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr

I have a tibble `cv_data` is like:

```
 A tibble: 5 x 4
  splits           id    train              validate         
  <list>           <chr> <list>             <list>           
1 <split [160/40]> Fold1 <df[,2] [160 × 2]> <df[,2] [40 × 2]>
2 <split [160/40]> Fold2 <df[,2] [160 × 2]> <df[,2] [40 × 2]>
3 <split [160/40]> Fold3 <df[,2] [160 × 2]> <df[,2] [40 × 2]>
4 <split [160/40]> Fold4 <df[,2] [160 × 2]> <df[,2] [40 × 2]>
5 <split [160/40]> Fold5 <df[,2] [160 × 2]> <df[,2] [40 × 2]>
```

each of element in `validate` contains two columns of data `X` and `Y` like:

```
            X             Y
8    5.1652551 -0.9588899139
12  10.2826634 -0.7893261511
14  11.2997726 -1.0062170535
18   6.1328676 -0.0125641656
19   8.4969333  0.8503936538
```

My goal is to arrange each tibble in `validate` by `X`. I wrote like this:

```
 cv_data %>%
   map(validate, ~arrange(data=.x, .x$X))
```

but received the error that

```
Error in as_mapper(.f, ...) : object 'validate' not found
```

Could anyone shed lights on the reason? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Try `mutate(validate = map(validate, ~arrange(data=.x, .x$X)))`

Comment: @stefan, Thanks! but the issue still persists: ```Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `validate`.
x no applicable method for 'arrange_' applied to an object of class "c('double', 'numeric')"
ℹ Input `validate` is `map(validate, ~arrange(data = .x, .x$X))`. ```

Comment: Try `cv_data %>% mutate(validate = map(validate, ~arrange(.x, X)))` The first argument to arrange is `.data` not `data`. (;